# C# Employee Search by Name

Tags: c#

I am working on this assignment for my C# class: 
Employee Search Create an application that connects to the Personnel.mdf database that you created in Programming Problem 1. The application's form should display the Employee table in the DataGridView control. The application should let the user specify a name in a text box and then search for that name in the Employee table. The application should display any rows that contain a full or partial match of the specified name.

I am having issues with getting the application to display any rows that contain a full or partial match to the specified name.

Here is what I have for my SQL SELECT statement:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, Name, Position, [Hourly Pay Rate] 
FROM Employee 
WHERE Name LIKE '%' + @name + '%'
```

Here is the code in my Form for the searchButton:

```
 private void searchButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.employeeTableAdapter.NameSearch
                (this.personnelDataSet.Employee, searchNameTextBox.Text);
        }
```

In my table, for example, I have Michelle Wilcox and Michael Gleason, when I type in Mich in the text box on the application and click search, I do not get any values back. I am expecting to see both of those rows in the table. 
Also, if I just put in the first name, Michael, nothing is returned. The only time I get the row returned is if I enter in the exact full name.

Any suggestions on where I should be looking to correct the program?

Comment: if you were to hard code the Like and try SELECT EmployeeID, Name, Position, [Hourly Pay Rate] FROM Employee WHERE Name LIKE '%Mich%' do you get anything back?

Comment: Yes, if I hard code it, then I get the 2 rows returned. Unfortunately, that's not the only combination of search criteria I need to look for. Another example would be John Carson and Steve Johnson.  If I search for John, I should expect both those values to return. But if I hard code Mich, it won't work that way.

Comment: I'd confirm that @name really contains the value you think it does then.

Comment: I'm calling the employeeTableAdapter.NameSearch method in my code, and then the first argument is the dataset's Employee table, and the second argument is the searchNameTextBox, won't that second argument be passed in the SQL query's @name parameter?  I thought that's what I was doing. Am I wrong?

Comment: Can you post the code for the `employeeTableAdapter.NameSearch` function?

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the collation used by the SQL Server on the backend, more information here - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322112

The reason I bring that up is because "LIKE comparisons are affected by collation" as discussed here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Changing your SELECT statement to below may prove this out:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, Name, Position, [Hourly Pay Rate] 
FROM Employee WHERE Name 
LIKE '%' + @name + '%'
 OR LIKE @name + '%'
```

Comment: I read through the articles, thank you for them. I also tried your suggestion, but that didn't work. I'm still not getting the query to pull all the rows.  In fact, right now I have to have the exact full name in the search in order to get a row displayed.

Comment: Can you share the table design?

Comment: Can you execute the following and share the collation?  
    SELECT CONVERT (varchar, SERVERPROPERTY('collation'));

Comment: I got it to work. I changed the Data Type for the Name column from nchar to nvarchar.  Thank you so much for all the advice and help.

Comment: Glad I was able to help!